# What does address 0 mean in perf?

Tags: profiling, glib, perf

Profiling some code with perf, I get a stack trace that looks like this:

```
+    7.29%     0.00%  test     [unknown]            [.] 0000000000000000                                                               ▒
-    5.71%     5.68%  test     libc-2.21.so         [.] __memset_sse2                                                                  ▒
   - __memset_sse2                                                                                                                     ▒
      - 55.60% 0                                                                                                                       ▒
         + 97.30% 0                                                                                                                    ▒
           2.70% 0x19                                                                                                                  ▒
      + 20.92% 0x7                                                                                                                     ▒
      + 16.83% 0x34                                                                                                                    ▒
      + 2.69% 0x8                                                                                                                      ▒
      + 2.00% 0x9                                                                                                                      ▒
      + 1.00% 0x11                                                                                                                     ▒
        0.97% 0xe                                                                                                                      ▒
+    5.55%     0.23%  test     libc-2.21.so         [.] epoll_ctl                                                                      ▒
+    4.62%     0.15%  test     [kernel.vmlinux]     [k] nf_hook_slow                                                                   ▒
+    4.60%     0.23%  test     [kernel.vmlinux]     [k] tcp_data_queue                                                                 ▒
```

I have no idea what the `0` addresses mean. When I press the right-arrow key, I don't get an option to disassemble the code, so I can't get any clues from there either.

How do I figure out what's calling memset?

Comment: Have you compiled the binary with debug info? `gcc -g`

Comment: It sounds like `-fomit-frame-pointer` from the libc; try to install debugging symbols for libc, and try to switch perf to dwarf with option, recommended by Gregg http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html: `perf record -F 99 --call-graph dwarf ./YOUR_TEST`